# Building docker image from Dockerfile: cannot start container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I was trying to build a new image using an existing Dockerfile. Looks like it did resume from a cache at some point. But the build didn't evolve much from very simple steps like apt installs/updates. How do I get more information on the actual error and how to recover from that state? great appreciate!

```
...
Step 15 : RUN apt-get install -y cron
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2a6dea37a20
Step 16 : RUN apt-get install -y vim
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a2a5dea37a19
Step 17 : RUN apt-get install -y debsecan
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cc2aa4c994c2
Step 18 : RUN apt-get install -y links
 ---> Using cache
 ---> abb32d4543f6
Step 19 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 68c12197bcfd
Cannot start container 68c12197bcfd12f39e669dc4ba1f1dc07a6fde07c675b6e763...: [9] System error: exit status 1
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.el7.14.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      8f9d39a-unsupported
 Built:           Thu Sep 15 11:51:19 2016
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.el7.14.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      8f9d39a-unsupported
 Built:           Thu Sep 15 11:51:19 2016
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64



FROM debian:latest

MAINTAINER me@example.com

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN apt-get install -y dialog
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y net-tools
RUN apt-get install -y cron
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y debsecan
RUN apt-get install -y links
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN cd /var/www && mv html htmlapache
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/repo
RUN touch /var/www/html/index.html
COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN apt-get -y install salt-master
CMD [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: Have you read through [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1322886)?

Comment: Show the Dockerfile

Comment: Dockerfile please :) Because there looks to be some funky stuff going on in that output.

Comment: Why do you call `apt-get update` many times when it only updates the list of available packages and their versions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `apt-get update` many times. It is also a good practice to update and install all packages in one row because it create only one layer in docker image

```
FROM debian:latest

MAINTAINER me@example.com

RUN apt-get update \
    && upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y sudo dialog curl wget vim net-tools apt-utils net-tools cron vim debsecan links apache2 salt-master
RUN cd /var/www && mv html htmlapache
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/repo
RUN touch /var/www/html/index.html
COPY entrypoint.sh /
CMD [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: same results. Sending build context to Docker daemon 10.24 kB
Cannot start container  8ae238... : [9] System error: exit status 1

Comment: Try to restart docker service because it looks like docker pipeline is corrupted